# Odoo15 Import Time Off use employee barcode for Employee instead of employee name

Tags: time, import, odoo, config, odoo-15

I has develop an application with odoo 15. I have difficulty with action import for model hr.leave. By default it use employee.name for searching employee. But i want it use employee.barcode instead.

[Timeoff import screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDLQc.png)

[Employee fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KU4Mg.png)

Any solution for that problem? Thanks!